# How to Spawn Child Processes that Don't Die with Parent?

Tags: c++, linux, fork, parent-child, spawn

I have a C++ program that acts as a watchdog over others. If it detects that a process is no longer running, it restarts it via `system`. The problem is, if I kill the watchdog process, any processes it has started up also die.

```
void* ProcessWatchdog::worker(void* arg)
{
    //Check if process is running
    if( !processRunning )
        system("processName /path/to/processConfig.xml &");
}
```

The new child process gets started correctly, and runs without any  problems. But when the parent (now this `ProcessWatchdog` process) dies, the child dies too. How can I spawn a child process that is fully independent from the parent?

I've tried using `pclose` and `popen`, running shell scripts that start processes, and a few other tactics, but to no avail. I'm ignoring `SIGHUP` signals in the child processes, but they still die.

So ideally, I'd like to tell the system to start a process that is wholly independent from the parent. I want the child's `trace` to end with the child, and for it/the system to have no idea that `ProcessWatchdog` started it in the first place.

Is there a way I can do this?

I'm writing this in C++, on Linux.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make child process spawned with system() keep running after parent gets kill signals and exits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945189/make-child-process-spawned-with-system-keep-running-after-parent-gets-kill-sig)

Comment: I don't think using system is a good idea....

Comment: Why is not using system a good idea? Besides the obvious security issues? I'm doing this on an embedded system in a very controlled environment, and I'm not worried about erroneous system calls. Is there another reason I should be wary?

Comment: @zachd1_618 for the security issues and if /bin/sh doesn't exist you are going to have some kind of problem

Comment: @Alexis thanks for the info. In the future I'll be careful, but in this instance the system is closed and controlled and security isn't an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `system` with `setsid` before the process name.

```
system("setsid processname /path/to/processConfig.xml &");
```

This will launch the program in a new session.

Answer (score 5):

This one is a bit old but didn't get a complete answer. Here is what I have done on an embedded system to spawn a bash child with no relation to the parent.  Note that I execl a bash shell and then run my command in another bash shell. This may not be necessary in your situation.  For me it allowed me to do some I/O redirection that didn't work properly without it.

The two important concepts are the setsid() and the double fork(). The combination of these two prevents a zombie from being created when the orphaned child completes, as well as preventing the orphaned child from being killed if the parent completes.

There are many other issues that could come up, like inherited I/O handles, working directory, etc, but this code does the basic job.

```
int spawn_orphan(char* cmd) {
    char command[1024]; // We could segfault if cmd is longer than 1000 bytes or so
    int pid;
    int Stat;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) { perror("FORK FAILED\n"); return pid; }
    if (pid == 0) { // CHILD
        setsid(); // Make this process the session leader of a new session
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) { printf("FORK FAILED\n"); exit(1); }
        if (pid == 0) { // GRANDCHILD
            sprintf(command,"bash -c '%s'",cmd);
            execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", command, NULL); // Only returns on error
            perror("execl failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        exit(0); // SUCCESS (This child is reaped below with waitpid())
    }

    // Reap the child, leaving the grandchild to be inherited by init
    waitpid(pid, &Stat, 0);
    if ( WIFEXITED(Stat) && (WEXITSTATUS(Stat) == 0) ) {
        return 0; // Child forked and exited successfully
    }
    else {
        perror("failed to spawn orphan\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `system(...)` it is not multi-threading safe.

```
int pid = fork();

if(pid==0)
{
  int rc = execv("processname", "/path/to/processConfig.xml &");
  if(rc == -1)
  {
    printf(stderr, "processname failed to start. %d", errno);
  }
  ...
}
else
{
  //continue with the parent
}
```

Comment: execv need a char** in second param

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid the use of system.

> Do not use system() from a program with set-user-ID or set-group-ID
>          privileges, because strange values for some environment variables
>          might be used to subvert system integrity.  Use the exec(3) family of
>          functions instead.

and also if you want to check the return value or anything else

Just go for `execl`

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
pid_t pid = fork()
if (pid == -1)
{
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else if (pid == 0)
{
  if (execl("processname", "processname", "/path/to/processConfig.xml", NULL) == -1)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}
else
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested by the [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) library function (internally using two nested [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) syscalls). After that, use the relevant [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall (or related [exec(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) functions)...

You should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com) for more.

Answer (score 0):

There's an execvp example in https://github.com/w-A-L-L-e/wash/blob/master/src/wash.cpp. Passing command line args is sometimes an issue with exec* functions from unistd and getting the environment passed can be some work. Anyway, hope it helps...