# start on certain PID c++

Tags: c++, pid

I'am trying to start batch file on certain PID, or get PID what program started on. I really have no idea how to do that.

```
    system("start C:\\testing\\vw.bat");
    Sleep(2000); //1000 = 1s
```

After this code is executed I need to close "vw.bat", but not close other batch files that are running.

Comment: Do you have the restriction that `vw.bat` cannot be altered? Because it's probably a much simpler task if you can just alter that script to start its dependent scripts and then kill itself.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682623.aspx may get you headed down a fruitful direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFO si{};
si.cb = sizeof(si);

BOOL success = CreateProcess("start C:\\testing\\vw.bat", NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, "C:\\testing\\", &si, &pi);
if (success)
{
    int pid = pi.dwProcessId;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code for reference. Code-only answers have low utility and are often confusing.

Comment: Sure. But this was a low quality question with no attempt of even googling the answer. Maybe I should have left that as a hint in a comment though.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the PID of your process using system-dependant system calls. For instance, on linux, using `pidof`. Now, please note using the `system()` function is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913446), and other ways of doing what you want exist, like [spawning a child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599096), which will let you kill the process easily.